# Data caching in Retrofit2

Tags: android, caching, retrofit2, okhttp, offline-caching

I did a project with retrofit2 and it works well. Project has 2 parts and each part gets data(Json object) from server with retrofit2. Now, I want to add cache system. I searched but I didn't find a good example. I have data which are object, string, integer(not image). I guess okhttp3 is best cache for my project. Can you explain best way for caching and can you share a good example. My plan:

- I will get a cache version from server with retrofit2.
- I will check version. If it is updated, it will show cached data. If not, it will get new data from server.
- Also, it will work offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used TinyDB for caching in android.

Answer (score 1):

To do that you'll need to implement a local database. I recommand you to use Room its quite simple to understand it.

You can find documentation here : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html